# Command-line password manager that uses SSH key to authenticate

Tags: command-line, software-rec, password

I'm looking for a command-line password manager, much like [pwsafe](http://nsd.dyndns.org/pwsafe/), but one that features SSH key authentication. That is, I'd like to be able to add my SSH key to the authentication when opening the password file, so that I do not have to remember yet another password but can use my SSH key to unlock my other passwords.

Pwsafe is compatible with Counterpane's Win32 PasswordSafe, which is a feature I do not need. I only need command-line access and the possibility to easily copy passwords to the clipboard.

Does such a program exist?

Comment: Why not use your password to unlock your ssh key?

Answer (score 3):

I like using [KeePass](http://www.keepassx.org/), but it doesn't support command-line usage directly. It does sport an API though, and some others have tried to mend the problem by supplying a command-line frontend using that API. All pulled from the [forum thread](http://www.keepassx.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=44)

1. A python frontend to the Keepass API: [python-keepass](https://github.com/brettviren/python-keepass)
2. [KPcli](http://sourceforge.net/projects/kpcli/)

Other:

1. [Password Gorilla](https://github.com/zdia/gorilla/wiki/), written in tcl/tk, supposed to handle command-line usage based on [pwsafe](http://nsd.dyndns.org/pwsafe/).

None of them are able to use your ssh key, probably since password storage isn't really a prime candidate for public key encryption (even though it certainly would be convenient). With KeePass it's possible to use your private ssh keyfile as additional cryptographic tie-down, but that's more for adding complexity rather than reducing it.

Answer (score 1):

I saw a recent recommendation of [cpm](http://www.harry-b.de/dokuwiki/doku.php?id=harry%3acpm) Which looks perfect. Unfortunately the link for source download appears to be broken, I emailed the author about it, but have not received a response as yet.

Answer (score 1):

There's a fork of [cpm](https://github.com/comotion/cpm) on github, since the project hasn't seen any activity from the original author in a fair while.

Answer (score 0):

[KeePassC](http://www.nongnu.org/keepassc/), is a curses-based password manager compatible with KeePass v.1.x and KeePassX that supports keyfile authentication (as of version 1.3).

It is lightweight with only two dependencies, and works well.